# Print interface name to console like class names in chrome dev tools

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Angular v8 w/ TypeScript and currently I have a bunch of redundant classes and it's becoming a pain to keep them in sync with changes with my backend models. The solution to this is to use Swagger and it works like a charm.

My backend is C# and I am using swagger code-gen to generate my front-end client along with its models. It's pretty slick and I'm really liking it.

However, I am looking for a way to make the model names print to console in dev tools like they do classes (with the name of the class). However, since I'm swagger seems to only generate interfaces instead of classes, chrome just spits it to the console as a JSON object.

**Is there a way to get chrome dev tools to print the interface name next to the object?**

```
class Person {
    public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  constructor(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
  }
}

interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

console.log(new Person('joe', 'dirt')); // friendly console message
console.log(<IPerson>{firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe'}); // can't tell what type this is
console.log({firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe'} as IPerson); // can't tell what type this is
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/yf8kowqn/

[image]

I'm thinking that there isn't since interfaces don't actually end up as anything like classes do. Just seeing if there's any options out there to make it happen

Comment: Add a build step with custom hook that automatically converts the interfaces into classes. IDK how exactly, just an idea. Or just make that hook add a non-enumerable `__interface__` property on the objects.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about that but then i'd essentially have to wrap each swagger generated service so it 'news up' the returned class. Otherwise, it's still just an object without a type. Maybe there's a swagger way to force classes in place of interfaces. Haven't researched that part yet. The second part sounds interesting though. Need to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

A class object can be directly translated to JavaScript and therefore it has a type in the console as any other class. An interface is an abstract thing that JavaScript wouldn't understand. Typescript casts both expression to a plain object which has no name. It does not instantiate a class because there is no connection between the class and the interface that could tell typescript to cast it to a class.

Comment: ...as mentioned in my question. I understand why it's happening. Just trying to think of ways to force it to be a class rather than an interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could "brand" your types.

`{ firstName: "something", lastName: "something" }` has the literal type `{ firstName: string, lastName: string }` but more generally just has the type `{ [key: string]: string }`. If you care, modify the API response, or adjust how the data is received into your app to "brand" the objects.

`{ __type: "Person", firstName: "something", lastName: "something" }`

This is also known as "[nominal typing](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html)"

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options. First as suggested in another answer add a tag of some sort to each interface which you can then print out. You could do this with an enum field which has a single value. You can also use this to add a version number to your schema definition which can be helpful when upgrading.

Secondly you can play around with the Mustache template used for the code gen. I've never done this but instructions are [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#modifying-the-client-library-format)